# How to turn off creating events when pressing enter in VS Windows Forms designer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I frequently find myself accidentally clicking enter when I'm laying out a form in Visual Studio. Whatever the focus is on when I accidentally hit enter, an event method is created in the code.

And you can't just delete the method because its defined in the designer file so you have to go in there and remove code from the designer. I don't find the Enter = create event functionality to be useful in the designer. Is there a way to turn that off?

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt it, no config for this in Tools + Options.  But be sure to use the normal workaround: type Ctrl+Z, it works.  And Y to dismiss the "are you really sure" message box.

Comment: yeah I guess that's a lot easier than the way I was fixing it before. Don't know why I didn't think of just doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If you just press Ctrl+Z,Y, any other unsaved changes you've made on the designer window (such as adding or moving controls) will be lost.

If you type **Ctrl+Tab** (to return to the designer window), and then type **Ctrl+Z**, only the insert of the empty event handler will be undone - other changes will be preserved.